# MVC How to count records in related Models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models, First is Relations, which is opened with Date, second model is Reservations, now i need to count record in reservations which have choiced Date of Relations. The tables is in Relationship relID from first i record in second table in DatumRID.

How to count records in Reservations which is related by ID to Relations

Model Relations:

```
  public tbl_relacii()
        {
            tbl_rezervacii = new HashSet<tbl_rezervacii>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int relID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DatumR { get; set; }
        public int sedista { get; set; }
        public string vozilo { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string shofer1 { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string shofer2 { get; set; }
        public string noteR { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tbl_rezervacii> tbl_rezervacii { get; set; }
        public string DatumForDisplay
        {
            get
            {
                return DatumR.ToString("d");
            }
        }
```

Model Reservations:

```
 public partial class tbl_rezervacii
    {
        [Key]
        public int rID { get; set; }
        public int AgentID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string karta_br { get; set; }
        public int DatumRID { get; set; }
        public int patnikID { get; set; }
        public int stanicaOD { get; set; }
        public int stanicaDO { get; set; }
        public decimal cena { get; set; }
        public bool povratna { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumP { get; set; }
        public string noteP { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_agenti tbl_agenti { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_patnici tbl_patnici { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_relacii tbl_relacii { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_stanici tbl_stanici { get; set; }
        public virtual tbl_stanici tbl_stanici1 { get; set; }
       public string relacija
        {
            get
            {
                return tbl_stanici.stanica + "=>" + tbl_stanici1.stanica;
            }
        }
        public string relacijaP
        {
            get
            {
                return tbl_stanici.stanica + "=>" + tbl_stanici1.stanica + "=>" + tbl_stanici.stanica;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is Controller for Relations Index:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
               return View(db.tbl_relacii.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.DatumR));
        }
```

How to count records in Reservations then put Number of records to index of Relations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve using LINQ query. Please find the sample below.

```
var q = from d in Model.Reservations
        select new Relations
        {
            Count = d.Reservations.Count()
        };
```

Comment: Where i need to put this in Controller Index, or in VIew?

Comment: You need to put in controller inside action method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved simply.  In relations model i added just this:

```
   public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return tbl_rezervacii.Count;
        }
     }
```

And problem is Solved. Thank you